# $ \int\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \, dx $ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Given two functions $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})$, calculate
>
> $$ \int\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \, dx. $$

Observing that $f'(x) = g(x)$, this is very easy to do. Just take $u = f(x)$ and therefore $du = f'(x)\,dx$. Now we have

$$
\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \, dx = \int \frac{du}{u} = \ln |u| + C = \ln\left|\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})\right|+C.
$$

However, this solution is wrong. The correct one is $\ln|e^x+e^{-x}| + C$. I see how we could get that, just plug in $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ directly, and we get

$$
\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})}{\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})} \, dx.
$$

Cancelling the $\frac{1}{2}$'s and taking $u = e^x+e^{-x}$ and $du = (e^x-e^{-x}) dx$ gives us

$$
\int \frac{du}{u} = \ln|u| + C = \ln|e^x+e^{-x}| + C.
$$

I can't see where I made a mistake in my approach, and I'd be really grateful if you pointed it out.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks, I will do that next time. :)

Comment: I feel terrible mentioning it because I know you're only trying to be polite but could you remove the religious elements at the end?  There are likely many faiths none should be given a platform

Comment: @Karl With all due respect, I will not remove it. It is very good to try to propagate the Faith in all contexts of life. The mods may remove it, but hey, I did my best. Not to mention that my right to free speech will be trampled on in this instance.

Comment: I ment no offence honestly.  I'd just rather stick to maths.

Comment: May the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) support you in all of your pasta-related endeavours.

Answer (score 16):

Note that if $K$ is a constant, $\ln|K\cdot h(x)|= \ln|K|+\ln|h(x)|$. In other words, the $1/2$ in the log can get 'absorbed' into the $+C$ term.

Comment: Aaaaah, I see! But then that means that my solution $\ln|\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})| + C$ doesn't *by itself* (with $C = 0$) calculate the area under the curve $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Comment: It seems $f$ and $g$ are reversed in your comment. It should, in the sense that
$$
\int _{0}^x \frac{g(t)}{f(t)}\,dt = \left.\ln|\frac{1}{2}(e^t + e^{-t})|+C\right|_{0}^x 
$$
$$
= \left(\ln|\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})|+C\right)-\left(\ln|\frac{1}{2}(1+1)|+C\right)=\ln|\frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})|
$$The $1/2$ is essential to make sure, starting at $x=0$, the area is $0$; otherwise, you'll be off by a constant.

Comment: Yes, $f$ and $g$ are reversed. Sorry about that and thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Using the identity: $ \log (\frac{a}{b})=\log(a)- \log(b)$

$\ln \frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})+C$
$=\ln (e^x+e^{-x})-\ln 2+C $
$=\ln (e^x+e^{-x})+C{'} $  (as $\ln 2$  is constant)